# Passing trace id from spring web app(using cloud sleuth) to non spring web application when hitting an api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing

I have two services  A and B

A : it is written in spring boot

B: it is web app written in java with custom framework

I want to pass trace id generated by Spring cloud Sleuth when calling api from A to B and then want to use it in logging in B .

IF B is also written in Spring Boot then Spring cloud Sleuth given this out of box

What is best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use RestTemplate or WebClient the trace information will be sent to B.

The headers are:

- x-b3-traceid
- x-b3-spanid
- x-b3-parentspanid

So you'll have to get these headers with a Filter in B and then you can for example write them to the Loggers MDC.